# Pointing subdomain to a new subsite in Asp.Net hosting

Tags: asp.net

Currently i have my website hosted in DiscountAsp.Net. I want to add a new website by creating a new subdomain to my existing main domain name. I understand discountasp.net only allows sub domain redirection to a page on my main domain. But, my requirement is the sub domain will be altogether new website which needs to operate with the subdomain. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/ and sub domain site is http://blog.stackoverflow.com where both are different website. i want similar setup for my website too. Any suggestion to do that in Discountasp.net or in a different asp.net hosting company..? I am ready to shift my hosting if the new host provides option for adding new website with sub domain.

Another question, Can i have my main website hosted in DisocuntAsp.net and subdomain to a different hosting account(for ex:godaddy)? Please let me know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts (keeping the one with the lowest user ID). You should have full control over your question now, which means you can add comments under answers, edit your question, etc. I converted the answer you wrote to a comment. Associating an OpenID with your account would probably be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about DiscountASP.net but check from your hosting control panel if there is a way to create new web application, if there is, then you can mark the folder that contains the files for "sub domain website" as a web application.
Between I run a small hosting company myself and we do provide the functionality to create separate website for sub domains :)

Comment: I do have create new web application option for subfolders. But how to associate my subdomin to the subfolder site? Thanks for the reply. Regards,
Bala